# Changing url of author page

Tags: urls, author

I have author page on my website: https://inwestujfinanse.pl/author/admin/ when I try to change it normally in https://inwestujfinanse.pl/wp-admin/profile.php nothing happens. Is there any way I can change it in the database or something? I don't want to install any additional plugin. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you really want to just change it directly in the database, you are looking for the `user_nicename` field (column) in the users table.

This is the value that WP uses for author archive URLs.